# Creating list with repeated items based on number of elements in another list

Tags: python, list, repeat

I'm having some issues creating/thinking how to resolve this.
I need to have 2 lists.
1 is the list of "users" and the other one is the list of "population" .
For each item in "population", I need to repeat each item on the "users" list.
Example:

| Population | Users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AA |
| 2 | AA |
| 3 | AA |
| 1 | BB |
| 2 | BB |
| 3 | BB |

Now, I get the data like this

```
User_list = [AA,BB]
Population_list = [1,2,3]
```

Any help would be nice, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share with us the code you've already written?

Comment: I havn't coded anything yet. I only wrote this in order to get the different users and population that I recieve from the source

        `users_list = ticket.data['user'].replace(";",",").split(",")
          population_list = ticket.data['population'].replace(";",",").split(",")`

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you capturing any values, or are you just printing to the terminal?

Comment: Logic: Iterate over the list of population, and for each value iterate over the list of users and append that specific value (from users list).

Comment: Expected output is to have the final list of users and population complete, I need to write that on an google worksheet with gspread. The thing is that the data could come like from the source (ticket.data[])  
user_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
population_list = [AA]
So I need this to be dynamic so that I can automate it

Comment: `itertools.product(population_list, user_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the comment by @Mathpdegeek497 above: you need to iterate over both lists in the order that you intend to get the output.

Of note, I'm assuming that you mean for the users AA and BB to be strings, so you'll need quotation marks around those. If they are *not* strings, and represent previously stored variables, no quotation marks are needed.

Code:

```
populations = [1, 2, 3]
users = ['AA', 'BB']

for user in users:
    for pop in populations:
        print(f"{pop} {user}")
```

Output:

```
1 AA
2 AA
3 AA
1 BB
2 BB
3 BB
```

Answer (score 1):

Logic with code:

```
#from the specs you have written, it seems you just need to repeat each element of  user_list that number of times
population = [1,2,3]
pop_length = len(population) #find the length of population
users_list = ['AA','BB'] 
final_list = []
for user in users_list:
    final_list.extend([user]*pop_length)

final_list #yields ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC']
```